# Getting TypeError - no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer when trying to save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-6

I am upgrading an RoR API app from Rails 3 to Rails 6. In one of the forms, I am getting `TypeError - no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer` error when saving.

This is my params defined:

```
def narrative_params
  name_params = (params[:narrative] || {})[:name].keys
  description_params = (params[:narrative] || {})[:description].keys
  params.require(:narrative).permit(:support_url, :guest_access_allowed, 
                   :disable_navigation, :disable_new_window, :enable_social_sharing, :customer_id, :user_id, 
                  :support_url, narrative_image_ids: [:_id], sub_groups_id: [:_id], template_id: [:_id], 
                  name: name_params, description: description_params)
end
```

This is the create method.

```
def create
  @narrative = Narrative.new(narrative_params)
  @narrative.user_id = @current_user._id
  
  # If no path_slug was sent or it was blank, find a unique one
  if @narrative.name and @narrative.path_slug.blank?
    @narrative.path_slug = SlugGenerator.get_unique_path_slugs(@narrative, @narrative.name_translations)
  end
  authorize @narrative

  if @narrative.save!
    if params[:container_id]
      populate_narrative_timelines_from_container(params[:container_id])
    end
    render json: @narrative.attributes.except("_slugs"), status: :created
  else
    puts @narrative.errors.inspect
    render json: @narrative.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

The SlugGenerator:

```
class SlugGenerator
  def self.get_unique_path_slugs(type_instance, localized_strings)
    unique_path_slugs = {}
    localized_strings.keys.each do |key|
      unique_path_slugs[key] = Mongoid::Slug::UniqueSlug.new(type_instance).find_unique(localized_strings[key])
    end
    unique_path_slugs
  end 
end
```

The data is getting saved to the database but the save method is returning this error. I have spent a lot of time on this, I don't understand what I am missing here. Please help.

Comment: Is there no line number the error is pointing to?

Comment: It points to the line where I'm calling save.

Comment: Can you post the block of code where save is being called? I would appear that you have a method that does something to one or more of the params and it's nil or something

Comment: @Int'lManOfCodingMystery I've added the create method and the SlugGenerator.

Comment: You need to get the complete stack trace to figure out what is actually failing.